# data is not retriving from outlook of office 365?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, microsoft-graph-calendar

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("dcb4a15***d745b428b2ac")
            .WithTenantId("8392***f0b-93b0-d4013318ea7d")
            .Build();
 var password = new SecureString();
            password.AppendChar('*');
            password.AppendChar('*');
            password.AppendChar('*');
UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword("username.onmicrosoft.com", password)
                .GetAsync();
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {
                new QueryOption("startDateTime", "2020-02-18T16:00:00.0000000"),
                new QueryOption("endDateTime", "2020-02-18T16:00:00.0000000")
            };

            var calendarView = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.CalendarView
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .GetAsync();
```

above code is written to get a calendar view in c#.net, but it is not working. I don't get any data from the calendar using a graph, I am using bot framework 4, I have added microsoft.graph,microsoft.graph.auth package, microsoft.identity.client
[image]

Comment: You'd better not contain any personal information int the post, I have edited your post.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code in the Main method, so I use Task.Result instead of Await. I can get the calendarView as expected.

```
UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            User me = graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword("username.onmicrosoft.com", s)
                .GetAsync().Result;
            var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {
                new QueryOption("startDateTime", "2020-02-12T16:00:00.0000000"),
                new QueryOption("endDateTime", "2020-02-18T16:00:00.0000000")
            };

            var calendarView = graphClient.Me.Calendar.CalendarView
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .GetAsync().Result;
```

I get one result as I have only one event between '2020-02-12' and '2020-02-18'. I noticed that you used the same time as startDateTime and endDateTime. You need to check if you have calendar events between the startDateTime and endDateTime.

[image]

[image]

Comment: should I use this code in the main method of  Program.cs

Comment: @Priya I just tested the code in the Main method, you should put it where you need it.

Comment: @Priya Inside `OnMessageActivityAsync`

Comment: I use the above code, but still, show error "One or more errors occurred. (Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request.
)"  in bots exception at  Microsoft.Graph.User me = graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword("Tejaswini@indica.onmicrosoft.com", password)
                .GetAsync().Result; , @Tony Ju , I  have used redirect uri of app urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

Comment: I got this error The application '13febApp2nd' asked for scope 'Calenders. Read' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Contact the app vendor, @Tony Ju

Comment: @Priya You have a spelling mistake. You should use `Calendars.Read`, not `Calenders.Read'

Comment: Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'. , allowpublicclient = true in manifest and toggle of defaultclienttype is yes , @Tony Ju

Comment: @Priya Try to add Mobile and desktop applications platform, not web platform.

Comment: @Priya Refer to my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60199911/10504999

Comment: Wui, what should I checked Access Token or Id Token in implicit grant

Comment: it gives me Microsoft.Graph.Auth.AuthenticationException: Code: generalException
Message: Unexpected exception occured while authenticating the request. , as i selected access token,@ Tony Ju

Comment: @Priya There is no need to enable  implicit flow(access token or id token)

Comment: @Priya If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Error Image]

I got above error for following code having my credentials

```
UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            User me = graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword("username.onmicrosoft.com", s)
                .GetAsync().Result;
            var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {
                new QueryOption("startDateTime", "2020-02-12T16:00:00.0000000"),
                new QueryOption("endDateTime", "2020-02-18T16:00:00.0000000")
            };

            var calendarView = graphClient.Me.Calendar.CalendarView
                .Request(queryOptions)
                .GetAsync().Result;
```

[image]