# How do I check if a BlobClient was instantiated properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm terribly confused as to how to see if my `BlobClient` service is setup and connected properly. I've tried getting some parameters within the BobClient class, but the only ones available are the ones that I set in the definition.

If my credentials are in a local JSON file, how do I pass that into `BobClient`? If not, are there any options for passing in credentials that exist in a local file and instantiating `BlobClient`?

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
client = get_client_from_auth_file(ComputeManagementClient, auth_path='azure_credentials.json')
service = BlobClient(account_url="https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/",
                         container_name='learn',
                         blob_name='class/courses.xlsx'
                         )

print(service.account_name()) # Returns: myaccount

with open(r'C:\Data\class\courses.xlsx', "rb") as data:
        service.upload_blob(data=data,
                            blob_type='BlockBlob',
                            overwrite=True
                            )
```

Comment: Are you looking for ways to instantiate an instance of BlobClient using client credentials?

Comment: I think so? I'm not sure what the alternative is

Comment: Is this sample what you want?https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/bd99ea5059c3a90c45b051c4113de03aeb73a8ae/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_authentication.py#L88

Comment: Not exactly. I'm trying to get `BlobClient`, not `BlokServiceClient`. I tried creating `token_credential` and passing that into BlobClient but still am getting the same error. Do I need to create a BlobServiceClient first before being able to create a BlobClient?

Comment: @simplycoding Could you please tell me how you create `token_credential `?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access Azure blob storage with Azure AD auth, you need to assign Azure RABC role (**Storage Blob Data Owner**, **Storage Blob Data Contributor** or **Storage Blob Data Reader**) to service principal or AD user. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)

For example
1. create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role for the sp.

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# it will assign Storage Blob Data Contributor to the sp at subscription level
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "mysample" --role Storage Blob Data Contributor --scopes <the resource id of storage account>
```

[image]

2. Code

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
tenant_id=''// sp tenant 
client_id=''// sp appId
client_secret='' // sp password
token_credential = ClientSecretCredential(
       tenant_id,
       client_id,
       client_secret
   )

from azure.storage.blob import  BlobClient
service =BlobClient(account_url='https://blobstorage0516.blob.core.windows.net/',container_name='test',blob_name='help.txt',credential=token_credential)
result=None
with open('D:\help.txt', "rb") as data:
       result= service.upload_blob(data=data,
                            blob_type='BlockBlob',
                            overwrite=True
                            )
print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: Still a little confused. My current user has role of Owner for all of Azure. How do I find its application id?

Comment: @simplycoding if you want to use Azure AD user to access Azure blob, you need to assign Storage Blob Data Owner, Storage Blob Data Contributor or Storage Blob Data Reader to the user. Besides, since you use Azure AD user to access blob, you can use `InteractiveBrowserCredential` to connect storage. Regarding how to use it, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191090/unable-to-connect-to-azure-blob-storage-using-interactivebrowsercredential

Comment: @simplycoding Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: I don't know, that first command isn't working for me `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "mysample" --role Storage Blob Data Contributor --scopes <the resource id of storage account>` with obviously my account's settings after I run the first command. It outputs some weird error message of ` Changing "remote-learning" to a valid URI of "http://remote-learning",` with remote-learning being the name of my container